# Type error on recursive List joining function

Tags: haskell

While studying Haskell, I came across this function which attaches two lists to form a single list.

This function works fine:

```
attach :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
attach [] l = l
attach (x:xs) l = x:(attach xs l)
```

But on the 3rd line, when I move the `x:` to the other side, it doesn't work. Why is that?

```
attach :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]
attach [] l = l
attach (x:xs) l = (attach xs l):x
```

Comment: The type of `:` requires us to use it as `headElement : tailList`, so we can't use it to append an element at the back as in `list : element`.

Answer (score 3):

If `attach` is meant to return a list, then you're trying to use `:` with the list as the left hand argument, and the item as the right hand argument.

This is opposite to the type signature of `:`.

```
Prelude> :t (:)
(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]
```

Comment: Is there any reason the type signature has the head before the list?